# Overriding Nginx cookbook default_enabled_site

Tags: nginx, chef-infra

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to disable the `default_enabled_site` in Nginx.

```
# My Cookbook
/cookbooks/my-server-book
- /recipes/
- /attributes/
metadata.rb

# Opscode Nginx
/cookbooks/nginx
```

I have `override['nginx']['enable_default_site'] = false` into my `/cookbooks/my-server-book/attributes/default.rb` file, but it looks like the Nginx cookbook is override my changes

```
Recipe: nginx::commons_conf

* template[nginx.conf] action create (up to date)
* template[/etc/nginx/sites-available/default] action create (up to date)
* execute[nxdissite default] action run (skipped due to only_if)
```

Any insights will me much appreciated.

I've tried the following in the node.json file with no avail:

```
{
  "nginx": {
    "default_site_enabled": false
  },
  "run_list": ["recipe[main]"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute[nxdissite default]` - this tells you that the default site has been disabled (the configuration file will always be created but not symlinked into the currently enabled configuration directory) so your overrides seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how to use the execute[nxdissite default] command. This is really helpful. In regards to my issue, I ran chef-solo without changing any attributes at first. This created the 000-default virtual host file which in turn will stay on the server, even if I change the attribute "default_site_enabled": false in the node.json or my Cookbook's attribute default.rb file. The reason I beleive is the file is already created, therefore, needed to delete the 000-default from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled or disable it first, before making changes to attribute file.